# Intuition for sampling random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I have recently come to understand random variables from the perspective as deterministic measurable functions $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. I've been rereading some old statistics text books and realized that in this framework I no longer understand what it means to sample something.

For example, in a recent text, I read something along the lines of "you can sample a geometric random variable with parameter $p$ by flipping a $p$-weighted coin and counting the number of flips until tails is turned". I am not sure how to intuitively interpret this as a random variable in this measure theory framework.

Somewhat similarly, when texts say "sample i.i.d $X_1,\ldots, X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$" what exactly does this mean? By what process do we actually accomplish this? Does this just mean that we explicitly choose a bunch of functions $X_k: \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying equality of distribution functions $F_{X_k}(\alpha) = \Phi(\alpha)$ and independence of laws: $\mathcal{P}_{(X_i, X_j)} = \mathcal{P}_{X_i}\times \mathcal{P}_{X_j}$?

Any intuitive clarifications would be really helpful! Huge plus if there's a nice way to formalize these methods for sampling and sampling i.i.d etc.

Comment: Related question: [q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3479938/independent-observations-via-measure-theory/3480096) and [q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455773/are-elements-of-a-sample-i-i-d-realizations-of-the-same-random-variable-or-real/3455797).

Comment: So the answer to the first question basically had the same interpretation that I had: create random variables with the same distribution whose joint distribution can be factored out, but what I'm really interested in is defining the process of sampling better. By what means do we actually construct these variables? Creating $n$ independent copies of a variable $X$, isn't *really* copying, so how do we define this procedure?

Comment: A good example is that if $F$ is the CDF for a random variable $X$, and $F$ is invertible, and $U$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$, and $Y = F^{-1}(U)$, then the random variable $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$. Proof: $P(Y \leq x) = P(F^{-1}(U) \leq x) = P(U \leq F(x)) = F(x) = P(X \leq x)$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume two things:

(i) On the interval $(0,1)$, we can define a probability measure that gives each inverval of the form $(a,b)$ with $0<a<b<1$ the measure $b-a$.

(ii) On the product set $(0,1)^n = (0,1) \times \cdots \times (0,1)$ ($n$-dimensional unit box), we can extend the measure from (i) to a new probability measure that gives each rectangle of the form $(a_1,b_1) \times \cdots \times (a_n,b_n)$ with $0<a_i<b_i<1$ measure $(b_1-a_1) \cdots (b_n-a_n)$.

In words, we are assuming that we have a way of measuring subsets of $(0,1)$ and $(0,1)^n$, respectively, that will return the length of an interval and the volume of a box, respectively, when applied to these simple sets.

To generate a single random variable $X$ with the $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution, you proceed as follows: Define the measurable function $X: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ (on the probability space defined by the measure in (i)) so that $X(u) = F^{-1}(u)$ for any $u \in (0,1)$, where $F$ is the cdf of a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variable. ($F$ is continuous and strictly increasing, so it is invertible.)
To see that $X$ so defined has the correct distribution, note that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
P(\{X \leq x\}) = P(\{u : F^{-1}(u) \leq x\}) = P(\{u: u \leq F(x)\}) = P([0,F(x)]) = F(x).
$$
This is a way to define $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ as a measurable function from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

You can then define $n$ independent copies $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ as follows: First create a function 
$$
X(u_1,\ldots,u_n) = (F^{-1}(u_1),\ldots,F^{-1}(u_n))
$$
from $(0,1)^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Then define the coordinate maps 
$$
\pi_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = x_i
$$
from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. The composite functions $X_1 = \pi_1 \circ X,\ldots,X_n = \pi_n \circ X$ then give you $n$ random variables that are all defined on the same probability space $(0,1)^n$, with the measure given in (ii). By using the fact that $\{X_i \leq x_i\} = [0,F(x_i)]$ (by the same argument as above), and the fact that the measure of a box is its volume by (ii), you can easily show that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. with distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: And the reason that the $X_i$ are independent is because the generated algebras of each dimesnion corresponding to the $u_i$ are independent?